# Outputting php array results into a HTML table

Tags: php, html

I have a php function I made that checks passwords to see if they are strong or not. I want to put the output into a table with three columns. The first labeled "Password" the second labeled "Strong" and the third labeled "Tests Failed". How do I take what I have and make it so each iteration of the foreach populates the table with the information sent to and from the function? Sorry HTML is not really my strongpoint.

```
Password    Strong    Tests Failed
abcd         No       no capital, no special char, no uppercase
```

That is an example of what I want each password to do, here is what I have:

```
<?php

//function to test password
function validatePassword($pwd) {
    //create array to store test information
    $messages = [];
    //test for at least 8 characters
    if (strlen($pwd) < 8) {
        $messages []= "too short<br />";
    }
    //test for max length
    if (strlen($pwd) > 16) {
        $messages []= "too long<br />";
    } 
    //test to see if password contains number
    if(!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $pwd)) {
        $messages []= "no number<br />";
    }
    //test to see if password has capital letter
    if(!preg_match("#[A-Z]+#", $pwd)) {
        $messages []= "no capital<br />";
    }
    //test to see if password has a lowercase letter
    if(!preg_match("#[a-z]+#", $pwd)) {
        $messages []= "no lowercase<br />";
    }
    //test to see if password has special character
    if(!preg_match("#[^0-9A-Za-z]#", $pwd)) {
        $messages []= "no special character<br />";
    }
    //test to see if password contains a space
    if (strpos($pwd, ' ') > 0) {
        $messages []= "has space(s)<br />";
    }
    //password passed all tests
    if (empty($messages)) {
        return "Password is acceptable<br />";
    }
    //return the array
    return implode("\n", $messages);
}

//create and initialize the array to hold passwords to be tested
$Passwords = array("donkeypass", "password", "Prebyt1na!", "1234", "abcd", "narW1@asndk", "pasS w0rd!", "maK%sh1ft", "mypasswordisthebestpasswordever!23493484023", "sD123#vAr2@y7");

//loop through each element of the array
foreach ($Passwords as $value) {
    //send each element to function to validate passwords and print results
    echo "Password Tested: " . $value . "<br /> Results: </br>" . validatePassword($value), "<br /><br />";
}

?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to change the return value when the password is acceptable so it was easier to handle the messages in the table!

For the rest, I'm sorry I used echo for the HTML, I was using a web PHP tester and it didn't allow embeded HTML :(

Copy and paste your code here to try
http://phptester.net/

```
//function to test password
function validatePassword($pwd) {
    //create array to store test information
    $messages = [];
    //test for at least 8 characters
    if (strlen($pwd) < 8) {
        $messages []= "too short<br />";
    }
    //test for max length
    if (strlen($pwd) > 16) {
        $messages []= "too long<br />";
    } 
    //test to see if password contains number
    if(!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $pwd)) {
        $messages []= "no number<br />";
    }
    //test to see if password has capital letter
    if(!preg_match("#[A-Z]+#", $pwd)) {
        $messages []= "no capital<br />";
    }
    //test to see if password has a lowercase letter
    if(!preg_match("#[a-z]+#", $pwd)) {
        $messages []= "no lowercase<br />";
    }
    //test to see if password has special character
    if(!preg_match("#[^0-9A-Za-z]#", $pwd)) {
        $messages []= "no special character<br />";
    }
    //test to see if password contains a space
    if (strpos($pwd, ' ') > 0) {
        $messages []= "has space(s)<br />";
    }
    //password passed all tests
    if (empty($messages)) {
        return 1;
    }
    //return the array
    return implode("\n", $messages);
}

//create and initialize the array to hold passwords to be tested
$Passwords = array("donkeypass", "password", "Prebyt1na!", "1234", "abcd", "narW1@asndk", "pasS w0rd!", "maK%sh1ft", "mypasswordisthebestpasswordever!23493484023", "sD123#vAr2@y7");


echo '<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Pass</td><td>Strong</td><td>Tests Failed</td>
    </tr>';

    //loop through each element of the array
    foreach ($Passwords as $value) {
        //send each element to function to validate passwords and print results
        $strong = validatePassword($value) == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no';
        $msg = validatePassword($value) != 1 ? validatePassword($value) : 'Password is Acceptable';
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$value.'</td> 
            <td>'.$strong.'</td>
            <td>'.$msg.'</td>   
        </tr>';

    }
echo '
</table>';
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I helped, remember to mark the answer as soon as you're able.

Answer (score 1):

Do not implode the messages array. Rather put the result (Yes, No, etc.) in it as the last element. Then you can retrieve it with array_pop(). To get an HTML table do something like that:

```
echo "<table>";
foreach($Password as $value){
    $out = validatePassword($value);
    $last = array_pop($out);
    echo "<tr><td>$value</td><td>$last</td><td>" . implode(",", $out) . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```